# I am passsing an xhtml tag ID in onPageLoad('TableID') function

Tags: xhtml, onpageloadstring

Javascripts are in `script.js` file which I have called in the xhtml file.

But it is throwing error at line where I have calling `onpageload` function saying " object expected.

However, if I have the scripts on same XHTML file, it is working fine.

Comment: Could you complete (edit) your own question with the xtml part where you declare the javascript ? And where you are using it ?

Answer (score 0):

As specified in [HTML4 specifications for Scripts](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1), do you declare your external javascript like this ?

```
<script src="external.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

IE (but other browers may too) requires that you *open and close* the script tag.
**The end tag of the `script' element is not optional**

Answer (score 0):

make sure you call your scripts after the page is fully loaded - use document.onload event handler or

```
<body onload="">
```